# enctype multipart form-data input-field Access

Tags: html, forms, jsp, servlets, enctype

I have a JSP-Page with a form with `enctype="multipart form-data`:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upLoadForm" method="post" action="aktionFileUpload.do">
<input type="file" name="userfile_1" id="file_element"/>
<input type="hidden" name="parameterHelper" id="parameterHelper" value="test"/>                     
</form>
```

The file upload in my servlet works, but I get no access to the input field with:

```
 request.getParameter("parameterHelper");
```

I searched in the internet and there I found that the servlet recieves it as `MIME-Type` or such other thing. But I did not find any solution, so that I can read the field.

Can you Help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does form with enctype="multipart/form-data" cause problems accessing a hidden field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827778/does-form-with-enctype-multipart-form-data-cause-problems-accessing-a-hidden-f)

Comment: thank you... that was the answer.